# Uniform convergence on compact sets passes holomorphicity - prove using Morera's

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $\{f_j\}$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions on a domain $U$ and if the sequence converges uniformly on compact subsets of $U$ to a limit function $f$ then $f$ is holomorphic on $U$. Prove this using Morera's Theorem.

My attempt is short. Take any closed curve $\gamma \in U$ and noting the ability to pass the limit under the integral for a compact subset of U surrounding $\gamma$ (which exists because $U$ is a domain): $$0=\lim_{j\to \infty}\oint_\gamma f_j(z)dz=\oint_\gamma \lim_{j \to \infty}f_j(z)dz=\oint_\gamma f(z)dz$$

so that $f(z)$ is holomorphic by Morera's Theorem.

I am uneasy with this solution so am open to critiques!

Comment: Depending on what can be taken for granted, it may be necessary to say why you can interchange limit and integral. A real problem is that you don't (necessarily) have $\oint_\gamma f_j(z)\,dz = 0$ for an arbitrary closed curve in $U$, you only know that for closed curves not winding around any point in the complement of $U$ (closed curves nullhomologous in $U$). But that's all Morera needs.

Comment: Is uniform convergence on compact sets enough to justify exchanging the limit?

Comment: Yes, that is enough (since the trace of the path is compact).